# Why there is some delay caused by a JavaScript function that isn't supposed to run immediately?

Tags: javascript, synchronization, settimeout, delay

I have two functions, `showhide` and `getSourceCode`. I want `showhide` to execute (hide a dialog box) immediately after submit, but `getSourceCode` is pretty long so I make it execute later. However, some delay still occurs between I click submit and `showhide` comes to effect. When I remove `getSourceCode`, the dialog box can disappear immediately, but it is always delayed as long as there is `getSourceCode`, even when I `setTimeout` it.

```
document.querySelector("[type=submit]").onclick = function (event) {

    showhide('dialogBox');

    if (options[0].checked) {
          setTimeout(getSourceCode(),10000);          
    }
}

function getSourceCode() {

    var htmlastext = ajax("something.aspx");

    function HTML(text) {

        this.fullCode = (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(text, "text/html");
        this.scripts = this.fullCode.querySelectorAll("script[src]");
        this.style = this.fullCode.querySelector("link[rel=stylesheet]");
        this.images = this.fullCode.querySelectorAll("img");

        this.replaceContent = function (content, element, tag) {
            var newElement = this.fullCode.createElement(tag);
            newElement.innerHTML = content;
            element.parentNode.replaceChild(newElement, element);
        }

        this.modify = function () {

            var externalContent;
            var serverpath = window.location.origin;

            for (var i = 0; i < this.scripts.length; i++) {
                externalContent = ajax(this.scripts[i].src.slice(serverpath.length));
                this.replaceContent(externalContent, this.scripts[i], "script");
            }

            externalContent = ajax(this.style.href.slice(serverpath.length));
            this.replaceContent(externalContent, this.style, "style");


            var removeTagList = [
                this.fullCode.getElementById("logout"),
                this.fullCode.getElementById("saveHTML"),
                this.fullCode.getElementById("dialogOverlay"),
                this.fullCode.querySelectorAll("script")[4],
                this.fullCode.querySelector("link")
            ];

            for (i=0; i<removeTagList.length; i++) {
                removeTagList[i].parentNode.removeChild(removeTagList[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    var htmlDoc = new HTML(htmlastext);
    var html = htmlDoc.fullCode;
    htmlDoc.modify();
    htmlastext = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(html);

    var txtarea = document.createElement("textarea");
    txtarea.innerHTML = htmlastext;
    htmlastext = txtarea.value;
    document.getElementById("encodedSourceCode").value = btoa(htmlastext);

}
```

Why does delay occur in `showhide`? Aren't JavaScript functions synchronous? Isn't `setTimeOut` able to prevent the parameter function from execution before the timeout? How can I hide the dialog box right after submission, without removing `getSourceCode`?

Comment: `setTimeout(getSourceCode(),10000)` you are immediately executing the function here when you add the `()` in `getSourceCode()`. Just do `setTimeout(getSourceCode,10000)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```
setTimeout(getSourceCode(),10000);
```

because `getSourceCode` function **gets called immediately** (because of `()` after it), and only its return value passed to [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout).

**Remove the parentheses** after your function, then, your function will be passed to `setTimeout`, and it will internally call it.

```
setTimeout(getSourceCode,10000);
```

Comment: It's solved and thanks. Btw, do you know why does the code seem to be asynchronous before setting a timeout to a function? Aren't JavaScript functions synchronous by default?

Comment: @Ursidae What do you mean "*seems asynchronous*"?

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, I expect `getSourceCode` to run after the execution of `showhide` has finished by default, but now I need to set a timeout to `getSourceCode` in order to achieve this.

Comment: @Ursidae JS is sync by default. What you see is because the functions are executed as you expect, but there are graphic updates only, when a task (in this case `onclick` function) is finished, and because JS is sync, it will only happen after `getSourceCode()`. You can avoid this by splitting work into smaller tasks (that's what `setTimeout` do). You can even use `setTimeout` with 0 delay, to achieve this effect, because it will create a new task too.

Comment: I don't really get what you mean... What means 'graphic updates only'?

Comment: @Ursidae I mean graphic updates in the browser. Only when a graphic update occur, will the look of the website change: changes made in DOM are only visualised that time.